# Submodule dependencies and Visual Studio Projects - Creating an architecture with nonlinear dependencies

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, architecture

not sure if this is supposed to be on stack overflow but I have currently a problem creating an architecture for my C# project.

## Main Structure

#### There are three repositories:

- data storage
- parsing (essentially filling the data storage)
- working (using the data storage)

> The `working` repository needs the data storage as a project (included as a git submodule).
>
> The `parsing` repository needs also the data storage as a project (included as a git submodule).
>
> The `data storage` repository is independent from all other repositories.

---

## The Goal

A *fourth* repository is created that uses the `parsing` repository and the `working` repository. Note that both repositories depend on the `data storage`repository

## The Catch

What if the `parsing` repository depends on a different *version* of the `data storage` repository than the `working` repository. We don't want this to happen.

## The Question

How do I prevent any user from including both projects in Visual Studio Professional or Git if the submodule `data storage` version is different. How would you structure your repositories? Would you include the `data storage` repository as a submodule in both repositories or would you only include .dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to merge all of them into one repository.

Possible options would be:

- removing all Submodules and leaving false references --> The user has to set the cross references them self

  - this would mean, that cloning one repository may result in a non-buildable project, since the project references were set to non-existent projects
- merging all in one repository resolving the version problem and referencing problem and providing a out-of-the-box buildable repository

  - but loosing the separated git history and advantages of separated repositories and branches